# How to best normalize a data frame in R by column?

Tags: r, average, normalization

I have a dataset like the one below that I would like to normalize (0 to 1) by column.

What I have currently:

```
        2015 Value      2014 Value      2013 Value
China           500             400             450
Germany         890             760             700
Italy           240             210             200
```

What would be great to end up with:

```
            2015 Value      2015 Normed     2014 Value      2014 Normed     2013 Value      2013 Normed
China           500             0.5             400             0.5             450             0.5
Germany         890             1.0             760             1.0             700             1.0
Italy           240             0.0             210             0.0             200             0.0
```

After this step, I'd like to average each Normed column in a "total average".

I've tried a couple of things, but I'm not seeing how to do apply the function by column with a new column for each output. The lapply function seems to be the right track, but I'm not sure how to best use it. (I'm a newcomer to R trying to learn.)

I really appreciate your help. Sorry for the basic questions!

Comment: Could you show the calculation to get the values 0.5, 1.0, 0.0 for the 2015 Value.  Perhaps `do.call(cbind, Map(cbind , df, lapply(df, function(x) round(x/max(x), 1))))`

Comment: Those are made up values, but here is the equation to normalize on a 0 to 1 scale: (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x))

Comment: Try with `do.call(cbind.data.frame, Map(cbind , df, lapply(df, function(x) round((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)), 1))))`

Comment: @akrun Hmm, I'm getting this error when attempting that: "non-numeric argument to binary operator".

Comment: In your data, are the countries a column or are they just the row names?

Comment: Please check the `str(yourdata)` whether you have columns that not numeric or not

Comment: @G5W: They're their own column. So column one is "Country", c2 is "Value 2015", etc.

Comment: I think it is because you didn't show the 'Country'' name, we thought it is rowname.  I posted a solution with the fix for that

Answer (score 3):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the columns, do the normalization, `cbind` with the original dataset columns alternatively using `Map` and then `cbind` the `list` elements to a `data.frame`

```
lst <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) round((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)), 1))

res <- cbind(df[1], do.call(cbind.data.frame, Map(cbind , df[-1], lst)))
names(res)[-1] <- rbind(names(df)[-1], sub("Value", "Norm", names(df)[-1]))
res
#   Country 2015 Value 2015 Norm 2014 Value 2014 Norm 2013 Value 2013 Norm
#1   China        500       0.4        400       0.3        450       0.5
#2 Germany        890       1.0        760       1.0        700       1.0
#3   Italy        240       0.0        210       0.0        200       0.0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Country = c("China", "Germany", "Italy"), `2015 Value` = c(500L, 
890L, 240L), `2014 Value` = c(400L, 760L, 210L), `2013 Value` = c(450L, 
700L, 200L)), .Names = c("Country", "2015 Value", "2014 Value", 
"2013 Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

If starting with a data frame that is all numeric values, then it can be treated like an array, and a standard `apply` used:

```
data.df <- read.delim("data.tsv");
colnames(data.df) <- sub("^X","",colnames(data.df));

data.df[,sub("Value","Normed",colnames(data.df))] <-
    (apply(data.df,1,function(x){(x-min(x)) / diff(range(x))}));

> data.df
        2015.Value 2014.Value 2013.Value 2015.Normed 2014.Normed 2013.Normed
China          500        400        450         1.0   1.0000000        1.00
Germany        890        760        700         0.0   0.3157895        0.25
Italy          240        210        200         0.5   0.0000000        0.00
```